# Who wins in this flush vs. flush hand?

Tags: texas-hold-em

player 1 has 5⋄  3⋄

player 2 has 6⋄  8⋄

Cards on table:  2⋄  J⋄  9⋄  T♥  A♥

*Who wins and why? 
What would be the outcome if there were four diamonds in the community cards instead of three?*

Comment: I can't find the answer to this.... Both players have a flush with the highest card shared in the river... Player one holds another card of the same suit but player 2 holds a higher card in a different suit.... I believe the higher card wins...
But player 2 believes they win because they hold a sixth card of the same suit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comparing flush vs flush is exactly the same principle as comparing a high-card hand vs another high-card hand. The flush that has the bigger highest card wins. If they are the same, compare the 2nd highest cards in each flush, and so on. In your case, player 2's J9862 beats player 1's J9532, because the 3rd highest card of player 2's flush is better.

This principle doesn't inherently change whether there are three or four or five diamonds on the table, the rule is the same: What counts at showdown is the best *5-card-hand* that each player can make from the seven cards that are available. In your case, because at least one of each player's hole cards will count regardless of whether the turn or river are diamonds as well (the 2 from the board is too small to be played in those cases), and player 1's own diamonds are weaker than player 2's diamonds, player 2 will always win even if the turn and/or river are also diamonds, unless the turn and river happen to be exactly A and 4 of diamonds, giving player 1 a straight flush.